# Functions Integrable over finite interval

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

I have a particular problem and its about Darboux sums and integrable functions.
Here is a statement that is False, but want to demonstrate with example why its
false.
Here is the statement:

> Let P be a partition, defined by, P ={1,1.3,2} be a partition of the closed interval [1,2]. Let f(x) = 0 for the range x<1.5, and let f(x) = 4 for x>= 1.5 . The the upper sum U(f,P) = 2.8 and the lower sum L(f,P) = 0.
>   Therefore, function f is NOT integrable on [1,2] by the Darboux definition of the definite integral.

SO this statement is false. This function is integrable over this interval of [1,2].

My undestanding of the Darboux definition for integrable is that of, IF one can find a particular partition of a given interval such that L(f,P) = U(f,P), then the function is integrable over that interval by the Darboux definition.

I now want to find a partition of [1,2] such that, L(f,P) = U(f,P).

But I am having difficulty figuring out the partition, choosing the numbers for this to work.

Hope someone can figure it out.

Comment: In general it will be Impossible to find a partition such that $L(f,P)=U(f,P)$, in particular this applies to any strictly monotonic function $f$. Note that  integrability of $f$ in the sense of  means that $\sup\{L(f,P) \vert P\in\mathcal{P}\}=\inf\{U(f,P) \vert P  \in\mathcal{P}\}$, where $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of all partitions of the given interval.

Comment: Hi, if it will be that difficult to find "THE" partition of all possible partitions on this interval such that sup = inf, then how would one show that the function in this question actually is integrable by the Darboux definition?

Comment: Note that for partitions $P,Q$ with $P\subseteq Q$ the inequalities $L(P,f)\leq L(Q,f)\leq U(Q,f)\leq U(P,f)$. So one only needs to consider partitions $P$ wich contain $1.5$ as one point. But then $L(f,P)=0+\frac12 4=U(f,p)$. Thus for example $P=\{1,1.5,2\}$ is suitable.

Comment: Hi Jens Schwaiger, thanks for your reply. I think i get it. But when computing the  U(f,P) is the upper sum for the sub-interval [1,1.5) is this equal to zero because we have an open interval at x=1.5. If that is the case we choose the left-end point which would give zero. Just hoping you will clarify if I got this idea correct.

Comment: When calculating the expressions $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$ the suprema and infima in the subintervals are always taken with respectively to the *closed* subintervals. Compare for instance   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723771/darboux-sums-computations-of-lower-and-upper-sums?rq=1.

Comment: Hi, if we try to take the U(f,P)  on the closed interval, in this example, between [1,1.5], would this not lead to a value of not being 0. So we get at x=1.5 we go to to height 4, so U(f,P) = 0.5*4 then on next subinterval would be from 1.5 to 2, U(f,P) = 0.5*4, so hence when you say that L(f,P) = U(f,P) they will not be the same then. I want to know then how you got the U(f,P) to be equal to the L(f,P) when using closed intervals for each sub-interval in this particular case.

Comment: Hi, so if I cannot use sub-intervals that are only closed, I don't see how for this particular problem I can get  the computation to get L(f,P) = U(f,P), based on  your partition P={1,1.5,2}. Just to clarify it a bit more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76391/discussion-between-jens-schwaiger-and-palu).